# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: my_boardgames BUT ITS THERE

Tags: python, sqlite

im trYing to write to a table in sqlite thru python app.

the code looks as follows:

```
#skapa databasen och koppla till den
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('Minna_spel.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
print("Opened database successfully!!!")

#skapa tabbelerna i databasen

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_boardgames 
               (game_name text,
                genre text,
                recage int,
                playtime int,
                players int
                )""")

print("created tabel successfully!!!")
conn.commit()
conn.close()

def add_new_game():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Minna_spel.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    val_game_name = input("Namn?")
    val_genre = input("Genre?")
    val_rec_age = input("Rekomenderad ålder?")
    val_play_time = input("speltid?")
    val_players = input("Antal Spelare?")

    conn.execute("INSERT INTO my_boardgames (game_name,genre,recage,playtime,players)
VALUES (val_game_name,val_genre,val_rec_age,val_play_time,val_players)");
    print("spelet är nu sparat !")

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

im not sure what im doing wrong but as soon as i make al the inputs to the funktion add_new_games it fails with the statement :

sqlite3.OperationalError: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: val_game_name[image]

i check in the databse and sure enough it there. what am i doing wrong?

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*nb: I slightly reformatted the text-strings for readability by splitting the lines.*

You are not interpolating the variable values into the query string. The following line

```
conn.execute(
    "INSERT INTO my_boardgames "
    "(game_name,genre,recage,playtime,players) "
    "VALUES "
    "(val_game_name,val_genre,val_rec_age,val_play_time,val_players)");
```

Needs to be replaced with

```
conn.execute(
    "INSERT INTO my_boardgames "
    "(game_name,genre,recage,playtime,players) "
    "VALUES "
    "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
    (val_game_name, val_genre, val_rec_age, val_play_time, val_players));
```

### Additional Information

---

*As you mentioned in the comments that you are a programming novice, I will add more information*

*The following code will only use two columns to make the lines shorter and more readable.*

---

#### A naïve aproach

The most obvious (but inefficient, error-prone & insecure) solution would be the following:

```
conn.execute(
    "INSERT INTO my_boardgames "
    "(game_name, genre) "
    "VALUES ('" + val_game_name + "', '" + val_genre + "')")
```

The string-concatenation makes the code difficult to read, and you need to deal with proper value-quoting yourself, which is easy to get wrong. It is also very brittle and insecure as certain values can cause the query to become invalid, or (if maliciously crafted) can make the query do something completely different ([SQL-Injection Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ciNHn38EyRc))).

#### Improving Readability with String Formatting

A second approach may lead you to the following which makes the code more readable.

```
# Using traditional "printf-style" formatting
conn.execute(
    "INSERT INTO my_boardgames "
    "(game_name, genre) "
    "VALUES ('%s', '%s')" % (val_game_name , val_genre))

# Using "new-style" formatting
conn.execute(
    "INSERT INTO my_boardgames "
    "(game_name, genre) "
    "VALUES ('{}', '{}')".format(val_game_name , val_genre))

# Using f-strings
conn.execute(
    "INSERT INTO my_boardgames "
    "(game_name, genre) "
    f"VALUES ('{val_game_name}', '{val_genre}')")
```

These 3 versions are all technically the same solution. They replace special place-holders inside the string *before* sending it to the database library (SQLite in this case). The resulting SQL query-string is the same as the one using `+` for concatenating the strings. The code becomes a bit more readable, but the code is still brittle and insecure for the exact same reason as the first variant.

#### The right way to do it

This leads us to the final solution (the one in my original answer above):

```
# Using "new-style" formatting
conn.execute(
    "INSERT INTO my_boardgames "
    "(game_name, genre) "
    "VALUES (?, ?)", (val_game_name , val_genre))
```

There are some subtle but *important* differences:

- We send two values to the `execute()` function: The query string with question-marks (the placeholders), and the values that should be used for those placeholders (The earlier methods all sent only one value: The SQL string which we manually constructed with values).
- We don't replace the question marks ourselves. We let the DB library deal with this
- We don't need to worry about quoting (note that there are no quotes around the question marks).

This keeps the code readable and most importantly easy to maintain.

Letting the DB library deal with the placeholders allows the DB to decide how to quote the values properly which mitigates the aforementioned SQL-Injection attack.

Comment: hm ok im not sure i understand, im a novice in both python and sgl. what is it supposed to be instead of the question marks ?

Comment: You should be able to copy paste the code verbatim (with the question marks). They are placeholders that will be replaced automatically with the values of the second argument to `execute()`. Just try copy/pasting the code above. It should work.

Comment: As you mentioned that you are a novice, I've updated the answer with a lot of information concerning replacing values in SQL queries. I highly recommend the video I linked about SQL Injection attacks

Comment: Good that you expand on the sql-injection problem. I use to use this XKCD strip as illustration: https://xkcd.com/327/